# vb.net Serialize and Deserialize a list(of string) using json or other method

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization

I'm sure this is simple thing, but i've been staring at it for so long I can't think straight!  :)

I am getting a list of directories, I want to serialize this list, i will then save into a database field as nvartext and then later on pull the data back out and convert back to a list of string.  I'm having trouble on the DEserialize portion.

```
Sub SerializeDeserializeMyList
    Dim myDirectories as list(of String) = GetDirectories("C:\")
    Dim JSONString as string = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyDirectories)

    'ok new let's try to DEserialize the string

    'THIS DOES NOT WORK ->
    Dim myNewDirectories as list(of string) = jsonconvert.deserializeobject(of string)(JSONString)
End Sub

'this part works fine but i'm open to other suggestions on this    
Public Function GetDirectories(ByVal path As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim subfolders As New List(Of String)

    For Each subfolder As String In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path)
        subfolders.Add(subfolder)

        Try
            subfolders.AddRange(GetDirectories(subfolder))
        Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
            'Ignore this folder and move on.
        End Try
    Next subfolder

    Return subfolders
End Function
```

Any thoughts would be great appreciated.  I see bunch of entries for json deserialization for more complex objects, but nothing for a simple list of string.

Thank you in advance!
Chris

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of String))` ?  If the original object was a `List(Of String)` then I wouldn't expect to convert it to a `String`.

Comment: You are absolutely correct!  I knew i was looking at this toooo long!  With the code above i used:  
Dim NewDirectories as list(of string) <br>
NewDirectories = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of String))(UnEncrypted)